# Return ambiguous type object from function

Tags: c#

I want to return ambiguous type object from function :

```
private object NewObject()
{
  if (1==1)
     return new {"xyzzz",1};

  else 
       return new {"xux"};
 }
```

We are using .net 2.0.

Comment: Even if you can, you shouldn't. You shouldn't return anonymous types. Think about how'll you access it in the call site? (There are hacks, but why?)

Comment: Which version of visual studio you're using? If you're using Vs2008 or greater it is possible but no don't do that. Create a named type.

Comment: Whatever is the reason for you to use it, I want to know, are you getting compile time error?

Comment: and the **question** is?

Comment: I would recommend you never so this though. It's a seriously BAD idea, but;

Return it as an XML or JSON string if you insist? This way you know the object is a string, you can deserialise it to whatever object you want.

My biggest question is why you'd do that though?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but the legal syntax would be

```
new { Prop1 = "xyzzz", Prop2 = 1, }
```

and

```
new { Prop3 = "xux", }
```

You can only use a shorter syntax without `=` when you have things with names, such as simple names or member access with the `.` operator.

Also, you must use a C# compiler that understands the C# 3 syntax of anonymous type (as mentioned elsewhere). Targeting .NET 2.0 should be fine if the compiler knows C# 3 (like the one that comes with Visual Studio 2008 and later).